# Duplicate checks in query

Tags: apex

I have a custom object called connector in that I have a field called connectornumber I want to find the duplicates  for connectornumber by using SOQL query can any one help on this ..

Answer (score 5):

Try this. Run this query

```
SELECT Connectornumber__c, count(id) NrOfRecords 
FROM Connector__c 
GROUP BY ConnectorNumber__c
HAVING count(id) > 1
```

All the records that return are duplicated.

PS: I've just updated this post. The earlier one did not have the `having` clause.

Comment: You can even use HAVING in this case: `HAVING COUNT(Id) > 1`.

Comment: Goodness, I didn't even know we had having. Have to brush up on aggregate soql. Updated my post.

Comment: I thought about that and almost commented but...don't you want `count(Id) > 0`, which will be true for every returned result?

Comment: If I only want to return duplicates, `>1` is the right clause.

Comment: I guess it depends on the context. If you are in an `insert` trigger, you are looking for *any* existing matches. If you are looking for existing duplicates, you want *multiple* matches.

Comment: The OP did not give any of that detail. So I went with the standard approach.